# Neural Net backpropagation doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, neural-network, backpropagation

Lately I've implemented my own neural network (using different guides, but mainly from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14342/Designing-And-Implementing-A-Neural-Network-Librar)), for future use (I intend to use it for an OCR program i'l develop). currently I'm testing it, and I'm having this weird problem.

Whenever I give my network a training example, the algorithm changes the weights in a way that leads to the desired output. However, after a few training examples, the weights get messed up- making the network work well for some outputs, and making it wrong for other outputs (even if I enter the input of the training examples, exactly as it was).

I would appreciate if someone directed me towards the problem, should they see it.
Here are the methods for calculating the error of the neurons and the weight adjusting-

```
    private static void UpdateOutputLayerDelta(NeuralNetwork Network, List<double> ExpectedOutputs)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Network.OutputLayer.Neurons.Count; i++)
        {
            double NeuronOutput = Network.OutputLayer.Neurons[i].Output;
            Network.OutputLayer.Neurons[i].ErrorFactor = ExpectedOutputs[i]-NeuronOutput; //calculating the error factor
            Network.OutputLayer.Neurons[i].Delta = NeuronOutput * (1 - NeuronOutput) * Network.OutputLayer.Neurons[i].ErrorFactor; //calculating the neuron's delta
        }
    }

    //step 3 method
    private static void UpdateNetworkDelta(NeuralNetwork Network)
    {
        NeuronLayer UpperLayer = Network.OutputLayer;
        for (int i = Network.HiddenLayers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            foreach (Neuron LowerLayerNeuron in Network.HiddenLayers[i].Neurons)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < UpperLayer.Neurons.Count; j++)
                {
                    Neuron UpperLayerNeuron = UpperLayer.Neurons[j];
                    LowerLayerNeuron.ErrorFactor += UpperLayerNeuron.Delta * UpperLayerNeuron.Weights[j + 1]/*+1 because of bias*/;
                }
                LowerLayerNeuron.Delta = LowerLayerNeuron.Output * (1 - LowerLayerNeuron.Output) * LowerLayerNeuron.ErrorFactor;
            }
            UpperLayer = Network.HiddenLayers[i];
        }
    }

    //step 4 method
    private static void AdjustWeights(NeuralNetwork Network, List<double> NetworkInputs)
    {
        //Adjusting the weights of the hidden layers
        List<double> LowerLayerOutputs = new List<double>(NetworkInputs);
        for (int i = 0; i < Network.HiddenLayers.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (Neuron UpperLayerNeuron in Network.HiddenLayers[i].Neurons)
            {
                UpperLayerNeuron.Weights[0] += -LearningRate * UpperLayerNeuron.Delta;
                for (int j = 1; j < UpperLayerNeuron.Weights.Count; j++)
                    UpperLayerNeuron.Weights[j] += -LearningRate * UpperLayerNeuron.Delta * LowerLayerOutputs[j - 1] /*-1 because of bias*/;
            }
            LowerLayerOutputs = Network.HiddenLayers[i].GetLayerOutputs();
        }

        //Adjusting the weight of the output layer
        foreach (Neuron OutputNeuron in Network.OutputLayer.Neurons)
        {
            OutputNeuron.Weights[0] += -LearningRate * OutputNeuron.Delta * 1; //updating the bias - TODO: change this if the bias is also changed throughout the program
            for (int j = 1; j < OutputNeuron.Weights.Count; j++)
                OutputNeuron.Weights[j] += -LearningRate * OutputNeuron.Delta * LowerLayerOutputs[j - 1];
        }
    }
```

The learning rate is 0.5, and the neurons' activation function is a sigmoid function.

EDIT: I've noticed I never implemented the function to calculate the overall error: E=0.5 * Sum(t-y) for each training example. could that be the problem? and if so, how should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The learning rate `0.5` seems a bit too large. Usually values closer to `0.01` or `0.1` are used. Also, it usually helps in convergence if training patterns are presented in random order. More useful hints can be found here: [Neural Network FAQ (comp.ai.neural archive)](ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ.html).